# PHP posted data with complex character

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a log in page where user enter user name and password the posted data changed when the user enter complex character e.g

```
12@#$%432^&*;',89/-*+_'
it change to: 
12@#$%C2^&*;',89/-*+_'
```

the user can't loging

this is the controller to get the data

```
if ($_POST)
 {
      $name = trim($this->input->post('name'));
      $pass = trim($this->input->post('pass'));
 }
```

this the part of the html code

```
     <input type="text" id="user_login" size="22" tabindex="10" class="input" onclick="this.value = '';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'username') {
   this.value = '';
   }" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = 'username';
  }" 
name="name" value="<?php echo __t($dir_lang, 'user_login'); ?>">
<input type="password" class="input" size="22" tabindex="10" id="user_pass" size="22" tabindex="10" class="input" onclick="this.value = '';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'password') {
              this.value = '';
  }" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
         this.value = 'password';
  }" name="pass" value="<?php echo __t($dir_lang, 'user_pass'); ?>">

   <p>
     <input id="login-submit" value="<?php echo __t($dir_lang, 'logging_button'); ?>" tabindex="100" type="submit" />
       </p>
```

Comment: We'll have to see some code ...

Comment: It appears the `%43` got converted to `%C`. Might be something with urlencode.

Answer (score 0):

Found it 
in the directory 
system/application/config/config.php 
the xss filtering was true

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = true;
```

so i change it to

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = false;
```

now it's working perfectly